# Modify code at runtime to log return values in Java?

Tags: java, return-value, instrumentation

Is there any way of inserting code at runtime to log return values, for instance, using instrumentation?

So far, I managed to insert code when a method exits, but I would like to log something like "method foo returned HashMap { 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3 }"

I'm looking for a general approach that can also deal with, for instance, java.io.* classes. (So in general I'll have no access to the code).

I tried using a custom classloader too, but lot of difficulties arise as I cannot modify java.* classes.

Thanks for the help!
Sergio

Answer (score 2):

Check out [BTrace](http://kenai.com/projects/btrace/pages/Home). It's Java, and I believe it'll do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered AOP? (Aspect-oriented programming) - if by "I cannot modify java.* classes" you mean you don't have access to the uncompiled code, and cannot add configuration, etc., then that won't probably work for you. In any other case, check that link for examples using Spring-aop:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html

If not, you could consider solutions based on remote-debugging, or profiling. But they all involve "some" access to the original code, if only  to enable / disable JMX access.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you're looking for everything, the only thing I can think off is using a machine agent. Machine agents hook into the low levels of the JVM itself and can be used to monitor these things.

I have not used DTrace, but it sounds like it would be able to do what you need. Adam Leventhal wrote a nice [blog post](http://blogs.oracle.com/ahl/entry/java_debugging_w_dtrace) about it. The link to DTrace in the blog is broken, but I'm sure a quick search and you'll come up with it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Spring AOP, which is quite powerful, and flexible. To start you off on the method `foo`, you can apply an [AfterReturning advice](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#aop-advice-after-returning) to it as:

```
@Aspect
public class AfterReturningExample {

  @AfterReturning(
    pointcut="package.of.your.choice.YourClassName.foo()",
    returning="retVal")
  public void logTheFoo( Object retVal ) {
    // ... logger.trace( "method 'foo' returned " + retVal ); // might need to convert "retVal" toString representation if needed
  }      
}
```

The pointcut syntax is really flexible so you can target all the sub packages, components, methods, return values given the expression.

Comment: here are [examples](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-examples) of different pointcut expressions that you can use